# Como converter um byte[] de uma imagem para uma imagem jpeg para carregar no html?

Tags: java, html, java-ee, compressão-de-imagem

No html(jsp) de cadastro tenho um campo que o usuário cadastra a foto dele ficando a tag `img` com o seguinte resultado.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;Base64,/9/0kmkdmkewnsjdncijndcjdxncdjcdscjnccc/ccnkjdncnsjnidckcmokcmoskcmkosmcokmdscjncjncjcsnckdjncojnscjncdjnckmkdmcokscmksmdckcmsokcmnjncjemncmokkjcmdjsdccmslckjplqmkmokswkmxokamlamklmockmclmdkcmlodkcmokcmkmcokmsomcksmcsfhhgfrfcghjkuytredfhjolkjhsSWswjshuhuwhuhyhuimcoskcmkmsckmkmkcmc"
/>
```

Estou convertendo o trecho apos `Base64,` em um byte[] com o sun.misc.BASE64Decoder, conforme abaixo:

```
import Decoder.BASE64Decoder;
import Decoder.BASE64Encoder;

/**
* @author Tiago Ferezin
* 
* para o tratamento da imagem
*
*/
public class Imagem {

public static byte[] convertBase64StringToByteArray(String imagem){
    byte[] retorno = null;

    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        retorno = decoder.decodeBuffer(imagem);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retorno;

}

public static String convertByteArrayToBase64String(byte[] imagem){
    String retorno="";

    try {
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        retorno = encoder.encode(imagem);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retorno;
}

}
```

E gravo no banco o byte[] gerado.

Primeiro queria saber como antes de gravar no banco, pegar o tipo da imagem(png,ttf,jpg,psd) e converter para `JPEG`, e aí gerar uma array dela e gravar no banco?

Segundo, gostaria de saber como converto esse byte[] gravado no banco para uma String `data:image/jpeg;Base64,{byte[]}` para colocar em uma tag `img` em outra pagina JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ler uma imagem, você pode usar a classe [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). O método read() recebe um InputStream. Não conheço bem o overload que recebe diretamente uma URL (será que ele reconhece o “protocolo” data:?), mas é bem fácil converter para byte[] usando um [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). O formato de origem deve ser detectado automaticamente.

Para converter a outro formato, é só pegar a imagem retornada pelo read() e chamar o ImageIO.write() passando como parâmetro o formato de destino desejado. A saída será escrita num OutputStream, portanto você pode usar um [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) para obter os bytes gerados.

Para gerar a String e colocar na página, eu pergunto se não bastaria simplesmente concatenar "data:image/jpeg;Base64," + Base64.Encoder.encodeToString(bytes)? Se não houver nenhuma surpresa no format (ou “protocolo”) data:, deve funcionar.

Obs.: se for usar o Java 8, já existe um (de)codificador oficial de [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html), fora da package sun.misc, que corre o risco de ser removida (ou tornada inacessível) em futuras versões do Java.